# onClick clear class function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, onclick

I have the following code set-up to clear the class of the other tab when it's clicked. Its build in wordpress so there might be a bit of wordpress code in there. Basicly what i'm trying to achieve is when you click on tab1 the class of tab2 clears and the other way around, also when you click on tab1, tab1 should recieve a class. I believe my code should work but it doesnt. Does anyone know what i did wrong?

```
                            <ul class="tab-links">
                                <?php if(get_field('tab_1_-_naam', $id)): ?>
                                    <li class="active1"><a onclick="$(".active2").hide();" href="#<? echo $slug; ?>_tab_<?php echo $id; ?>-1"><?php the_field('tab_1_-_naam', $id); ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php if(get_field('tab_2_-_naam', $id)): ?>
                                    <li class="active2"><a onclick="setColor(this,'#FFF');". "this.style.color='#5D3B08!important';" href="#<? echo $slug; ?>_tab_<?php echo $id; ?>-2"><?php the_field('tab_2_-_naam', $id); ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".active2").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a link it removes the class from your parent his siblings (the `<li>`) and then you add a class to your own parent (also a `<li>`).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".active2").hide();
    $(".tab-links a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
       $('.active1 a').click(function(e){
          //make tabs2 inactive
          $('.active2').removeClass('active');
          // make tab1 active
          $(.active1).addClass('active');    
      });

      $('.active2 a').click(function(e){
        //make tabs1 inactive
        $('.active1').removeClass('active');
        // make tab2 active
        $(.active2).addClass('active');    
     });
  });
</script>
And In **active** class add css for active tab.
```